# Can the set of natural numbers have a injection with a finite set?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

My intuition says that is not possible, but i am not achieving a great formal proof

Comment: You can't have a formal proof without proper definitions. For instance, what does "finite" actually mean to you?

Comment: finite set is a set with a bijection between itself and a set I={1,2,3...,n} for some n.
This is the definition i have here

Comment: An injection is a bijection with the image. A set that injects onto a finite set bijects with the image, which is also finite. Hence, the set is finite.

Comment: @DonThousand  That assumes you know that a subset of a finite set must be finite.

Comment: I'd like to see this question reopened, but I can't vote for it in its present form. I suggest (1) incorporating the question already in the title into the body of the ... er ... question (this is always required in Maths.SE - the body of the question is expected to be self-contained, because the title is only a summary), and (2) incorporating the definition of finiteness given in a comment into the body of the question. I don't think anything more is needed, although I'm open to corerection ... er, correction.

Comment: Small point: "injection with" should be "injection into".

Comment: 1) First prove that no bijection exist between $\{1,....,m\}$ and $\{1,....,n\}$ if $n\ne m$.(You can use induction) As compositions of bijections are bijections this mean if a finite set has a bijection with $\{1,...,m\}$ it has no bijection with any other and a finite set has a unique cardinality.2) If $A$ is finite set of cardinality $m$ and $f:\mathbb N\to A$ consider $\{f(k)|k=1,...,m,m+1\}$ use pigeonhole to show there are two $j,k;j\ne k$ so that $f(k)=f(j)$.

Answer (score 2):

A function $f: \mathbb{N} \to A$ is injective if $n_1 \ne n_2 \Rightarrow f(n_1) \ne f(n_2)$. If the images of different natural numbers must be different, $A$ cannot be finite.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the pigeonhole principle, which is that if you have $n$ holes and $n + 1$ items you have more than $1$ item in at least one hole.

Apply that to the concept of an injection and you're well on the way to something formal.